# Pipe communication

Tags: c#, c

I am creating one application in which there are three components:

- EXE1
- WCF service
- EXE2

EXE1 writes data to pipe then WCF read the data and send it to EXE2.
But scenario is, EXE1 writes data to pipe in for loop.So i just want to know,suppose EXE1 had write data into pipe but wcf is doing some other work and not read that data yet.Now EXE1 trying to write second data.So in this condition whether the previous data is overrides or EXE1 waits for some time for wcf service.

I want to control this condition, until first data is not read by wcf EXE1 must have to wait for some time.i want to send data synchronously to EXE2.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As its named as *PIPE* data that goes in first comes out first and data in pipe is not overwritten.

For waiting to write before other end reads it: You better of controlling how much you read at other end (e.g. passing message length as first byte(s)). So reader knows how much it should read and reads only that much a time from pipe.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to make `WCF` service acknowledge a particular set of `bytes` that its going to  receive.

So `Exe1` sends 10 bytes and waits for WCF to acknowledge it.

If `WCF` doesn't acknowledge,`Exe1` would resend it(timeout)!

If `WCF` acknowledges it,you would send the next 10bytes and so on.....

Comment: but how the EXE1 know whether wcf read data or not.And Second data gets override to first one or first data will be deleted.

Comment: @sunilpol after sending some data to WCF,if it doesn't respond to you by sending acknowledgement such as a code word(some binary word of your choice) withing some time limit,you would know that WCF has not received the data.

Comment: k..i will do that.but tell me when wcf read data and now exe1 got acknolmnt now it writes 2nd data.the first data deletes automatically or overridden by 2nd data

Comment: @sunilpol I dnt knw about `WCF`.But I think u must edit the question and **tell more about your WCF service**.Have u created it and if so why not create a `thread` in `WCF` itself that specially listens to `Exe1`.

Comment: no pipe is created in EXE1 & wcf only read data when exe2 requests data

Comment: on different pc.EXE1 is on server and EXE2 is at client side